# In SQL, how do you get the top N rows ordered by a certain column?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, relational

I want to select the top N rows of a table, ranked by how high the number in one of their columns is.

I already have:

`SELECT * FROM movie ORDER BY worldwide_gross DESC;`

How can I get the first twenty?

If it makes any difference I'm using MySQL.

Cheers!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Definition: Limit is used to limit your MySQL query results to those that fall within a specified range. You can use it to show the first X number of results, or to show a range from X - Y results. It is phrased as Limit X, Y and included at the end of your query. X is the starting point (remember the first record is 0) and Y is the duration (how many records to display).
Also Known As: Range Results
Examples:

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10
```

This will display the first 10 results from the database.

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 5, 5
```

This will show records 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10

More from [About.com](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I believe:

```
SELECT * 
FROM movie 
ORDER BY worldwide_gross DESC
LIMIT 20
```

should do the trick. See also [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html).